# Writing an 'if' statement in order to login users using php/ mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I’m wondering how you write if statements using mysql/php.

I’ve got an employee table with all their details, ‘username’ and ‘password’ then a column called ‘admin’ with a 0 or 1 as well. The user can login using the "username" and "password" form boxes. How do I write it so that it checks if the username/password exists then checks if admin = 0 and directs them  to header location employee.php  else if admin=1 then directs them to header location admin.php?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: This is the code I've got so far...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    setcookie('username',$myusername,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day

if ('admin' == '0'){


header("location:employee.php");

}

else {

header("location:admin.php");

else {

header("location:fail.php");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Post your tried code. And the area where you facing problem.

Comment: You're using the deprecated `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead and use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injections. And what's the check `if('admin' == '0')`? It's useless, it will always be false. You have to get the results from the database! With the old function it should be `$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);` Then replace `'admin'` with `$result->admin` And then you got two else with no closing brackets or another if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this php code

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['username'])); // received from post/get
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['password'])); // received from post/get

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  if($row['admin']==1)
  {
     header("location:admin.php");
     exit;
  }
  else
  {
      header("location:employee.php");
     exit;
  } 
}
else
{
  // invalid username or password
  // code here to handle
}
```

Comment: Why you explain the old mysql_ functions in new code examples? mysqli_ will be the better choice. And you input $username and $password directly into the query without any form of escaping. But the user will use a form to fill $username and $password.

Comment: i put here the demo only $username and $password has the mysql_real_escape strings. by the way i am updating it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can try using a select box of value ADMIN and USER . You can validate the select box in the if statement

```
if(select=="admin")
{
verify with DB \\admin
Redirect
}
else 
{
verify with DB  \\ end user
redirect 
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: What is an "if loop"?

Comment: sorry will edit the post

Answer (score -1):

You posted every step. Just code it now.

Make a new mysqli connection.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
```

Define your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourtablename WHERE username=? AND password=?";
```

Create a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = mysqli->prepare($query);
```

Bind the values:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $submitted_username, $submitted_password);
```

Execute the statement:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Check if there is a result or not.

If there is a result, check if admin is 0 or 1 and redirect (in case of 1) to admin php with `header()`:

```
header('Location: admin.php');
```

You can get your selected data for example with [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Just study the examples from php.net for more information how to get data with mysqli.

Comment: Downvote explaination?

Comment: Thanks for downvote without comment what's wrong -.-

Comment: It wasn't me, i can't do the vote thing yet, I'm finding everyone's help very useful.

Comment: I know this...but normally when somebody downvote an answer then he should say why - to improve the answer. This downvote is just useless.